# GridSearchCV on a pipeline with standardscaler, PCA & lasso

Tags: scikit-learn

Assume that I am doing GridSearchCV on a pipeline with [StandardScaler, PCA & Lasso], where the grid search is over 2 values for a PCA parameter and 3 values for a Lasso parameter (thus 6 possible parameter combinations). When doing CV, for a given fold does the algorithm standardize only the train set in that fold (*i.e.,* not include the fold's test set for determining mean/variance of the standardizer) or does it standardize the entire data set outside of the folds (in which case there is only one Standardizing done for the entire grid search procedure)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` object containing a `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`, a `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` and a `sklearn.linear_model.Lasso`, and use this pipeline to make a cross-validated estimator using `GridSearchCV`, then the `StandardScaler` will estimate the parameters for centering and rescaling to unit variance only on the internal train fold.

When evaluating the pipeline on the test fold, the `StandardScaler` will use the stored means and standard deviations and subtract the train mean from the test set and divide the result by the train standard deviation.

So the answer is: **No**, the `StandardScaler` will not use the test set in any way to determine mean and variance of the data.

Comment: As an aside note: I am not sure that a lasso on PCA outputs is very useful.

Comment: Thanks Eickenberg. Why do you say lasso on PCA output won't be useful?

Comment: Because with PCA you have retransformed your input space into maximum variance components. Using a lasso on these amounts to selecting which of them you want to use in your model. You could probably just as well cross-validate on how many of the components you want to keep and just fit an OLS or possibly a Ridge on them.

Comment: Starting from using only component 0 to using `[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], ... , [0, ..., n_components]`

Comment: While my previous comment is very often valid, I think I may have just happened on a situation where some of the large variance vectors are precisely *not* the ones I would like to select :) -- in this case whitening using `PCA` and `lasso` can actually amount to a powerful tool!

Comment: can you please describe the situation and why not picking the large variance vectors will help while whitening with 'PCA` and 'Lasso` would work? Thanks.

Comment: Any situation where your main variance component is actually (structured) noise, and the signal of interest is captured by lower variance components. After whitening, i.e. balancing of the strengths of these vectors, a lasso should select the component containing the signal and not the one containing the noise.